# É possível fazer duas expansões diferentes de variável em uma única expansão?

Tags: bash

Tenho uma variável, em array, `$CLI_MODE`. Preencho-a através de uma leitura simples:

```
read -a CLI_MODE
```

Gostaria de pegar o valor do primeiro elemento minúsculo e, se possível, trocando `-` por `_`. Para pegar tudo minúsculo eu posso usar a expansão `,,`:

```
$ variavel=aBcDe--FG

$ echo ${variavel,,}
abcde--fg
```

Para fazer a substituição do traço por linha debaixo, faria assim:

```
$ variavel=aBcDe--FG

$ echo ${variavel//-/_}
aBcDe__FG
```

Como faço para obter o resultado equivalente a essas duas expansões? Como se fosse `,,` junto de `//-/_`? É possível fazer isso em uma única expansão?

Comment: Acredito que duas expansões não seja possível, mas talvez elas aninhadas, algo como `echo ${${variavel//-/_},,}`. Já tentou algo assim?

Comment: @Woss, acho que uma construção inválida, mas não custa tentar...

Comment: `bash: ${${variavel//-/_},,}: bad substitution` =(

Comment: No ZSH consegui fazer uma construção semelhante; `echo ${${variavel//a/T}//-/_}` resultou em `TBcDe__FG`, mas o `,,` também deu o *bad substitution*.

Comment: pois é, mas estou preso na Bourne Again... Pelo menos eu consigo acessar a posição `[0]` e fazer o `downcase`... como se a expansão posicional não interferisse nas demais expansões

Comment: Pelo que andei pesquisando, o bash parece não suportar *nested expansions*. Então um jeito de fazer em uma única linha seria usar uma das expansões e substituir a segunda por algum outro comando: `echo ${variavel//-/_} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` ou `echo ${variavel,,} | sed s/-/_/g`

Comment: @hkotsubo poxa vida. Por mais desagradável que me seja desagradável, ainda é uma resposta. De toda sorte, invocar duas expansões parece-me mais barato do que fazer um pipeline e invocar um executável (`echo` normalmente é o built-in, dificilmente o executável `/bin/echo`, quando a nível de shell script, então não estou contando-o)

Comment: Bom, coloquei uma resposta (só estava procurando referências na documentação). Mesmo que não seja a solução mais agradável, fica aí como opção :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do bash sobre expansões](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`. The value of parameter is substituted. The parameter is a shell parameter as described above (see Shell Parameters) or an array reference (see Arrays).

Ou seja, o parâmetro que é passado para a expansão deve ser um *shell parameter*. E se verificarmos a [respectiva documentação](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters), lá é descrito que este parâmetro deve ser uma variável, um [parâmetro posicional](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters) (como `$1`, `$2`, etc), ou um dos [parâmetros especiais](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) (como o [`$@`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994295) e o [`$#`](https://askubuntu.com/q/939620), por exemplo).

Mas ao tentar fazer uma expansão dentro da outra (como por exemplo `${${variavel//-/_},,}`), o resultado da primeira (a mais interna) é um texto qualquer, que não é um parâmetro válido, e por isso a expansão externa falha.

Sendo assim, uma alternativa para fazer tudo em uma única linha seria fazer apenas uma das expansões, e tratar a outra com algum outro comando. No seu caso, poderia ser uma das opções abaixo:

```
echo ${variavel//-/_} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

echo ${variavel,,} | sed s/-/_/g
```

---

Outras opções para bash podem ser consultadas [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415505) e [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189426) (não testei todas).

E outra alternativa, caso seja possível, é mudar de shell. O zsh, por exemplo, [suporta *nested expansions*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules).